# How to show database,table, columns with one mysql command in bash?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, format

I ma testing Dynamic Multiple Data Source so that I need to show tables in both database as format below:

```
database|table   |column1|column2
master  |customer|data1  |data2

database|table   |column1|column2
replica |order   |data1  |data2
```

At the moment, I use code as below, it's not pretty..., do you have any idea?

```
use master;
select database();
select * from master.customer;
select * from master.customer_order;

use replica;
select database();
select * from replica.customer;
select * from replica.customer_order;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the database and table names as fix strings to the sql statement:

```
select 'master' as `database`, 'customer' as `table`, master.customer.* from master.customer
```

Since database and table are reserved words, make sure they are enclosed by backticks (`).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you know why this can't be run in bash script? I put them to bash script, I got error "line 1: database: command not found", but basic select is ok, how can I do?

Comment: I know sql only, I do not know bash.

Comment: it is ok after change [`] to ['], then I add --table so that I got the same result with run in mysql. Thanks a lot!